# Android ScrollView (scrollable on both Horizontal and Vertical smoothly) on which content addable programatically and zoomable on pinch

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

I need a scrollview where I can add numbers of image and button programatically and on single tap, zoomable by pinch on both horizontal and vertical with smooth scrolling. [Here](http://db.tt/8Wsycjlh) a video what I need exactly. I have tried with Horizontal scrollview within a ScrollView. I can scroll smoothly. I can add item on single tap. I can't zoom now. Here is the sample code:

```
   public void setUpNoticeBoard(){

    canvasLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

    canvasLayout.removeAllViews();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsImage = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    final ImageView noticeBoard = new ImageView(this);
    noticeBoard.setLayoutParams(paramsImage);
    noticeBoard.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    noticeBoard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noticeboard));
    noticeBoard.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    canvasLayout.addView(noticeBoard);

    float xx = noticeBoard.getWidth();
    float yy = noticeBoard.getHeight();

    System.out.println("noticeBoard Width:" + xx + "And Height:" + yy);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

        int x= (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*3000);
        int y= (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*2000);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsNotice = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        paramsNotice.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

        final ImageView notice = new ImageView(this);
        notice.setLayoutParams(paramsNotice);

        Resources res = getResources();
        String imageName = "pin" + (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*8);
        int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName() );
        notice.setTag(imageName);
        notice.setImageResource(resourceId);

        canvasLayout.addView(notice);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float curX, curY;
    newPin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mx = event.getX();
            my = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            curX = event.getX();
            curY = event.getY();
            vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
            hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
            mx = curX;
            my = curY;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            curX = event.getX();
            curY = event.getY();

            vScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
            hScroll.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), (int) (my - curY));
            break;
    }

    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

    int x = (int) e.getX();
    int y = (int) e.getY();

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsNewPin = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    paramsNewPin.setMargins(x + hScroll.getScrollX() - 98, y + vScroll.getScrollY() - 250, 0, 0);

    final ImageView newPin = new ImageView(this);
    newPin.setLayoutParams(paramsNewPin);
    newPin.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin5);

    canvasLayout.addView(newPin);

    return true;
}
```

Now I need 1 thing Zooming on pinch(Whole content on layout will be zoom)
Thanks.

Comment: @SudarNimalan ScaleGestureDetectorCompat performs on a double tap followed by a swipe. But I need to zoom on pinch. Does it make any sense? I am not clear.

Comment: This may be useful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html